# window.scrollTo in Safari browser

Tags: python, selenium, safari

I want to take a full screenshot of my page.

I take max height of the page using JavaScript - it's bigger than one screen, so I need to scroll down a few times.

```
parts = []
height = 0

while height < page_height:
   driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, %d);" % height)
   image = Image.open(BytesIO(driver.get_screenshot_as_png()))
   height += img.size[1]
   parts.append(image)
```

I found that this scrolling is working on Chrome browser, but I have a problem with Safari.

Have you any idea, why?

Comment: You. Can use ashot library to get full page screenshot